# Google Apps script - IN operator for minutes

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I try to run a sequential code. First update should happen every 15 minutes, the second one always 3 minutes after the first one.

The code below runs every minute.

However, it never works in Google Apps Script. Any idea how to fix it?

I only came up with writing out the `in` clause to `==` and `or`. It does not look straight.

```
function update_per_1_min() {

var d = new Date();
var m = d.getMinutes();  

  var m = 16

  if(m in [1.0,16.0,31.0,46.0]){

    update_0()

  } else if (m in [4,19,34,49]) {

    update_1() 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`in` checks whether the expression is a *property* of the object. Arrays have properties like `0` for the first index, `1` for the second index, etc:

```js
const arr = ['foo', 'bar'];
console.log('foo' in arr);
console.log('0' in arr);
```

Properties are not the same thing as values, of course. It looks like you're trying to check whether the *value* is contained in the array, in which case you could use `.includes` (if you were able to use ES6), or `indexOf` for GAS:

```
function update_per_1_min() {
  var d = new Date();
  var m = d.getMinutes();  
  if([1,16,31,46].indexOf(m) !== -1){
    update_0()
  } else if ([4,19,34,49].indexOf(m) !== -1) {
    update_1() 
  }
}
```

(note that trailing zeros after the `.` in numbers is meaningless - feel free to leave those out entirely)